# Bold/Unbold rows in PyGTK TreeView

Tags: python, click, pygtk, glade, gtktreeview

I want to make some rows in my TreeView bold, and some not as I append them to TreeView, later on, I want to unbold rows on click.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you have a model that contains a column with some text and that a `gtk.CellRendererText` widget has a `text` property set to the column index in that model.

If you add a new column to that model you can use it to set the font weight used in every cell renderer. To do that just set the `gtk.CellRendererText` widget `weight` property to the new column index in the model and `weight-set` to `True`.

After that, you just need to set the font weight in the model using any of the `pango.WEIGHT` constants such as `pango.WEIGHT_NORMAL` and `pango.WEIGHT_BOLD`.

As an example, let's say that these are your model columns (one for the text, one for the font weight):

[image: Model columns]

and these are a couple of rows that you've added for testing:

[image: Model rows]

(Note that `pango.WEIGHT_NORMAL=400` and `pango.WEIGHT_BOLD=700`)

With this model, you create a `gtk.TreeView` with a column and a text renderer:

[image: Treeview hierarchy]

In the renderer you set the `text` property to the `text` column in the model:

[image: Cell renderer text]

and the `weight` property to the `weight` column in the model:

[image: Cell renderer weight]

The result that you obtain with the test data that you added to your model is:

[image: Final result]

Where you can see that the text is displayed with the font weight that is set in the model.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I read in doc thigks you just explained. But I don't know how to do that. How to access gtk.CellRendererText? I just created TreeView from Glade and I'm appending rows from my code to it. How can I get renderer from my TreeView, and how to set the gtk.CellRendererText widget weight property to the new column index in the model and weight-set to True? Should I do sth in glade or I do that programatically? I looked doc for gtk.TreeView and didn't find how to work with cell renderers. Can you explain a bit? Sorry, but this is the first time I work with GTK.

Comment: I added a complete example with screenshots. I think that should be completely clear.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was comfused because I missed the fact that font weight property can be binded to row value http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ikZ.png. Thank you very much!